# how to compile project without using Lombok plugin in intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

i have some restriction to download the plugins for intellij.
In this case how can i compile my app using lombok.

i have tried to paas lombok jar through VM options in run configuration but no luck. any suggestion will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use Lombok in your code, provided you instructed your build tool to have a build-time dependency.

Without the Plugin, that will result in a lot of red wavy underlines in IntelliJ. But the code would still compile and run.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: thank you for your response. yes, as you mentioned it will do compile and run without fail. i dont want to see any red wavy underlines in my workspace. is there any alternate to make it ?

Comment: Not without using the plug-in, unfortunately. IntelliJ uses its own parser for those, not javac or ecj. That parser is responsible for the red wavy underlines. The IntelliJ Lombok Plug-in's purpose is to make that parser happy, and allow for code completion.

Comment: In my office, restricted to install plugins. Is there any other way we can add lombok? I have the lombok jar file downloaded from jfrog maven.